# Dual external screens from a laptop

Tags: laptop, display

Is it possible to run two external screens of a laptop (plus the laptops own screen).

If so, how do you do this?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you should have at least one video output (vga, or hdmi) on the laptop. Then you can also get a usb-to-vga adapter kit, or usb-to-dvi. I recommend IOGEAR for the adapter.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If your laptop does not support it natively (i.e. by having two external display connectors) then you either need USB video cards (as mentioned in another comment), USB monitors, e.g. the Samsung LD220, or you need something like the the Matrox DualHead2Go - which shows up as one large screen to your laptop, and splits that onto two smaller real screens (but your laptop needs to be able to drive one large external screen).

Answer (score 0):

I'll toss in my favorite USB->DVI is [Village Tronic's ViBook](http://www.villagetronic.com/vibook/). They also make an [external video card enclosure](http://www.villageinstruments.com/tiki-index.php?page=ViDock) if you have a PCIe Card slot, which can handle [Quad](http://www.jaton.com/VGA/graphics_card_detail.php?pid=31),  [Quint](http://www.powercolor.com/us/products_features.asp?id=240), and [Hex](http://www.diamondmm.com/5870PE52G.php) port video cards (some realistic limitation may apply to certain situations).

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this all the time with my Dell laptop. I had a docking station and plugged two monitors into the dock. Then, I would plug the laptop into the docking station without opening it. Depending on the model, use the power button on the laptop or the docking station to turn it on and you will have two monitors running from one laptop.

Oh, to do this, you will also need a keyboard and a mouse plugged into the docking station.